# How to use 802.1X authentication with Edimax EW-7811Un USB Wi-Fii adapter?

Tags: wifi, usb, driver, authentication, 802.1x

Edimax EW-7811Un, Mac OS X, Snow Leopard, 10.6.8.

[image: Edimax EW-7811Un]

According to the manual, you can use 802.1X tunneled authentication with Windows (it is mentioned e.g. on page 23, [EW-7811Un User Manual](http://www.edimax.us/download/manual/EW-7811Un_Manual.pdf#page=23)).

However, the Wireless Network Utility under OS X (10.6.8) seems to have no option for 802.1X network authentication.

Since it's supported on Windows, the card obviously has the capability, so how is it possible to use it under OS X?

PS: I'm happy to edit any configuration file by hand and skip the graphical utility entirely, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You do all the work in the "Network" System Preference if memory serves.

I don't have a 10.6 box handy to check but under 10.8 and 10.9 you first add the correct certificate to your keychain then when you select any of the "Enterprise" security options and EAP-TLS as the mode you can tell it to use the correct certificate and the username.

I remember having to  write the instructions for doing this on 10.6.8 a few years back but can't find them. The process was highly similar though.

[image: Here's what it looks like in 10.9]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the question, but you can access to the 802.1X settings in the advanced window of network settings:

System Preferences > Network > Advanced > 802.1X

[image]
[image]

PS: Sorry for italian GUI

Comment: That is used for selecting an 802.1x "profile" that has been created using Profile Manager and pushed to the Mac using device management. It requires a Mac OS X Server somewhere to create and push but it is just the thing for organisations with a number of Macs to set up on an 802.1x net.